# Form Location not correct at the Form start

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

Why the form location doesn't correspond to the set location?

Here is the code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//stuff (.....)
MyForm form = new MyForm ();
form.WindowState = Settings.Default.MainFormWindowState;
//When the form is shown, it location will be != of Settings.Default.MainFormLocation. Why?
//The idea is to change the form location before it is first shown.
form.Location = Settings.Default.MainFormLocation;
form.Size = Settings.Default.MainFormSize;

Application.Run(form);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set the StartPosition to manual:

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```